# Conditional distribution between jointly normal and univariate normal random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, conditional-probability, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, X_3)^T\sim N_3(\mu, \Sigma)$, where

$$\mu = \begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix},  \Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

I want to find $(X_1, X_2)^T|X_3$.

I know that $(X_1, X_2)^T \sim N_2(\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\ 
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix})$ and that $X_3 \sim N_1(1, 2)$.

My definition of conditional distribution of MVN however initially requires the distribution of $(((X_1, X_2)^T)^T, X_3^T)^T$, of which I am not sure.

Is there another way around this that I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There may be a typo in your notes/book.  By vector, you seem to mean _column_ vector (e.g. your definition of $\mu$) and so $X= (X_1, X_2, X_3)^T$ is a column vector. Now, the usual meaning of $((X_1, X_2)^T, X_3)$ is just the _row_ vector $(X_2, X_2, X_3)$ for which you have no definition of a MVN unless that $((X_1, X_2)^T, X_3)$ should read $((X_1, X_2)^T, X_3)^{\mathbf T}$ which becomes $(X_1, X_2, X_3)^T$ under  the usual interpretation.

Comment: Please decide where you want to ask your question. [Cross posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3050302/321264) should be avoided in general.

Comment: Could you please explain what distinction you might be making between the distribution of $((X_1,X_2)^\prime,X_3)$ and $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate You are right, I was confused over the use of the transpose. I actually require the distribution of $(((X_1, X_2)^T)^T, X_3 ^T)^T$ which is of course $(X_1, X_2, X_3)^T$ for which we have the distribution.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Apologies and thanks for the heads up. Still a newbie.